# Converting python command line script into django app

Tags: python, django

I've inherited a python command line script "myscript.py" which has a number of classes and contains the following:

```
def main():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-a", "--all", dest="saveall",
                      help="Store all information", action="store_true",
                      default=False)
    options, args = parser.parse_args()
    output = options.output
    count = options.count
    saveall=options.saveall

    grabber = Grabber()
    grabber.run(count, output, saveall)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've tested this on the command line and it works. I want to turn it into a django app. I can put all the classes onto the app's view easily, but I'm not sure how to refactor the main function to trigger the app with the various options that are available via an http request to django. assuming I pass in the arguments with something like:

```
@csrf_exempt
def myscript(request):

    option1 = str(request.POST.get( option1, False))
    option2 = str(request.POST.get(option2, False))
```

How can I run myscript from within django, passing the options to it with minimal changes to the script?

Comment: I'd read the Django tutorial, which explains how to use django to process URL provided arguments, json variables in the body, or how to process query strings (ways to pass data from the client to your view) and then run the view accordingly.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Have you tried to write a custom Django command?